# How to implement code of other app in our android app?

Tags: android, jar

I have code of two android app say A and B. I want to implement code of A in B application. For that I made A as library (jar) and add it in B project. A itself contains activities and other classes. Now I want to call A's root activity on a button click and run all the flow in A in B app project. I also want to access the data saved by A in its App memory in B project.

When added jar in B project, 2 activities of A works fine. But then it crashes.

The error I am getting is here

```
02-19 12:35:59.260: W/dalvikvm(478): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
02-19 12:35:59.280: E/AndroidRuntime(478): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-19 12:35:59.280: E/AndroidRuntime(478): java.lang.NullPointerException: No application instance given
02-19 12:35:59.280: E/AndroidRuntime(478):  at com.fsck.k9.mail.store.StorageManager.<init>(StorageManager.java:526)
02-19 12:35:59.280: E/AndroidRuntime(478):  at com.fsck.k9.mail.store.StorageManager.getInstance(StorageManager.java:497)
02-19 12:35:59.280: E/AndroidRuntime(478):  at com.fsck.k9.Account.<init>(Account.java:262)
02-19 12:35:59.280: E/AndroidRuntime(478):  at com.fsck.k9.Preferences.newAccount(Preferences.java:111)
02-19 12:35:59.280: E/AndroidRuntime(478):  at com.fsck.k9.activity.setup.AccountSetupBasics.onManualSetup(AccountSetupBasics.java:285)
02-19 12:35:59.280: E/AndroidRuntime(478):  at com.fsck.k9.activity.setup.AccountSetupBasics.onNext(AccountSetupBasics.java:256)
02-19 12:35:59.280: E/AndroidRuntime(478):  at com.fsck.k9.activity.setup.AccountSetupBasics.onClick(AccountSetupBasics.java:324)
02-19 12:35:59.280: E/AndroidRuntime(478):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
02-19 12:35:59.280: E/AndroidRuntime(478):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
02-19 12:35:59.280: E/AndroidRuntime(478):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
02-19 12:35:59.280: E/AndroidRuntime(478):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-19 12:35:59.280: E/AndroidRuntime(478):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
02-19 12:35:59.280: E/AndroidRuntime(478):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
02-19 12:35:59.280: E/AndroidRuntime(478):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-19 12:35:59.280: E/AndroidRuntime(478):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
02-19 12:35:59.280: E/AndroidRuntime(478):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
02-19 12:35:59.280: E/AndroidRuntime(478):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
02-19 12:35:59.280: E/AndroidRuntime(478):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-19 12:35:59.290: W/ActivityManager(76):   Force finishing activity com.test.k9test/com.fsck.k9.activity.setup.AccountSetupBasics
02-19 12:35:59.822: W/ActivityManager(76): Activity pause timeout for HistoryRecord{408e0b70 com.test.k9test/com.fsck.k9.activity.setup.AccountSetupBasics}
02-19 12:36:09.939: W/ActivityManager(76): Activity idle timeout for HistoryRecord{407edcd8 com.test.k9test/.MainActivity}
02-19 12:36:15.170: W/ActivityManager(76): Activity destroy timeout for HistoryRecord{408e0b70 com.test.k9test/com.fsck.k9.activity.setup.AccountSetupBasics}
```

Can you please suggest any solution? Thanks in advance

Comment: just define all the activity in your mainfest file it will work, and can you give some more info what error you are getting

Comment: @KapilVats I am getting null pointer exception in a activity of A project. It is in No application instance found. Also there is a manifest in A. So should I need to define them again? Should I need to provide permissions also

Comment: Yes you need to define the again, and permission also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding with the "Call of A project"

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), nom.nom.example.A.yourClass);
startActivity(intent);
```

where in A.yourClass is A's Main Activity.

Regarding with the "Access of A's data by B's project"

try looking at [SharePreference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)  or [ContentProvider](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentProvider.html)